# The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1 with docker

Tags: docker, npm

Here is a dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

When I run `docker build .`, I got

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/6 : FROM node:alpine
 ---> 72ca8e2f26fa
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR '/app'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 39c33c7a6b1c
Step 3/6 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 79a79ca26be1
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 45e16e475139
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-05-27T22_06_22_293Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I fix that?

P.S. Be aware that I am using ubuntu 20.04 and I am very new in using docker.

**EDIT**

Here is the the index.js file :

```
const express = require('express');
const redis = require('redis');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient();
client.set('visits', 0);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  client.get('visits', (err, visits) => {
    res.send('Number of visits ' + visits);
    client.set('visits', parseInt(visits) + 1);
  });
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 8081');
});
```

Here is the package.json file :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "redis": "2.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

I don't think I have any error in the code or the package.

Answer (score 0):

EAI_AGAIN means the DNS server replied that it cannot currently fulfill the request.

If you get this error with Firebase Cloud Functions, this is due to the limitations of the free tier (outbound networking only allowed to Google services).

Upgrade to the Flame or Blaze plans for it to work.

Comment: It doesn't help with what you added. The error means that registry.npmjs.org cannot be resolved. What provider are you using? It looks like your provider won't let you use that server. A wild guess is that I guessed the problem right initially :)

Answer (score 0):

remove <''> from WORKDIR '/app'

like this

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).